# Suggestion: opt-in preference to allow anyone to view where I cast my votes

Tags: feature-request, voting, preferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make vote anonymity optional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38396/make-vote-anonymity-optional)

Because I want to know from others and I don't mind sharing.

Basically this is just a philosophy style of life. I love knowing more and more data.

I'm really not sure if this is a good idea. Maybe it could bring good to the community, maybe not.

So let's just hear the feedback! :P

edit: Also I wanted to know where I casted my votes myself.

Comment: Definitely would have to be opt-in though... and by default opt-out

Comment: Interesting idea.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38396/make-vote-anonymity-optional/ (not quite the same, but most answers apply)

Comment: @Shog9 thanks a lot for the link!

Comment: Funny how the "exact duplicate" question is now gone. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a lot of work, for what I think would be very little participation.

Comment: Maybe, but I guess that's what voting is for on feature requests.

Comment: I never thought it would be a lot of work. It seems like a couple simple queries to do, though I don't know how the DB is structured or how heavy that would be. But I totally agree in the very little participation. At least on the beginning it would. But I'd love to be surprised in realizing an increased participation later on and see how all this could turn out.

Comment: Well, since there will never be another answer, I might as well just accept this.